# What is the difference between plugins, modules, add-ons etc in PHP?

Tags: php, programming-languages

I have a little question I want to know what is the difference between Plugins/Modules/Add-ons in PHP?

Comment: Where did you come across this terms? They are not specifically related to PHP. Plugin: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plug-in_%28computing%29, Module: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_programming, Add-on: see plugin.

Comment: Please give your questions useful titles. "PHP Question :)" is not useful.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Pekka, the terms are meaningless.

If you are looking to build on your CMS, then you can take Joomla path.

It is explained in 
http://www.opensourcevarsity.com/joomlaadmin/l3diffbtncompplugmod 
and 
http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?p=1485432

In summary:
Components = A Mini Application. It adds new functionality. Example are: newsletter, forum, etc.
Modules = A boxed section on a webpage presenting information. It extends functionality of existing system.
Plugin = A script triggered by an event. It manipulates data before being presented to the user.

Answer (score 1):

There is no defined concept for neither of the three in PHP.

The only defined term is **extension** which describes a compiled library that is loaded into PHP - either through php.ini, or more rarely using [`dl()`](http://www.php.net/dl) -  and provides additional functions and classes that can be called from within the PHP script. Extensions are usually written in C (In fact, I don't know to what extent it's possible to write them in other languages)  You can find a list of PHP extensions [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/extensions.alphabetical.php).

Many frameworks and applications implement different kinds of add-ons and plug-ins, usually in the form of a framework that includes PHP source files.  It is impossible to tell more without knowing more about the context you came across these terms.

Comment: Yes, sorry about this.
Now actually I want to know what is the difference maybe we create a website and want to implement modules or plugins in our site, but since @Pekka I've see many frameworks have an directory called modules, plugins or add-ons just wanna to know is this the rest of those kinds ?

Comment: @Doctor there are many implementations for this out there. For example, Zend Framework has a built-in Plugin framework http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.plugins.html does that answer your question?

Comment: So imagine you have your own CMS website and want to implement modules or plugins into, what is the modules or what is the plugins which we want to implement, can you understand me?

Comment: @Doctor well, that depends on what your plugins do. Are you looking for hints on how to build a plugin framework?

Comment: Joomla has an own modules and plugins, what are they tools ?

Comment: @Doctor *the terms are meaningless*. They are used to describe an concept of adding PHP source files in some custom way. They have no defined meaning in the PHP world.